# Deleted all my hard-drive partition by mistake (g-parted)

Tags: 16.04, gparted

I think I have done one of the most stupid things in my life! I wanted to format a pen drive, so I opened g-parted and mindlessly started deleting all the partitions on the drive except one that I could not delete (i.e. ext4 ROOT C)... just to find out that I deleted all the partitions on my main hard drive!

I am writing from my computer which still functions well.
First thing I'll do is backing up my home folder, however, to do so I need to go home and thus put my computer to sleep. Will it still function once I turn it on again?

Is there any way I can repair my mistake or am I forced to reinstall everything from scratch?

Comment: If not rebooted, use fdisk to manually recreate table posts by srs5694 post34 on page#4:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1668247
If rebooted, you may have to use testdisk or parted rescue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
exec sudo -i
apt-get update
apt-get install testdisk
testdisk
```

Choose Create to instruct Testdisk to create a log file containing technical information and messages, unless you have a reason to append data to the log or you execute TestDisk from read only media and must create the log elsewhere.

Choose None if you do not want messages and details of the process to be written into a log file.

Press Enter to proceed.

All hard drives should be detected and listed with the correct size by TestDisk.

Use up/down arrow keys to select your hard drive with the lost partition/s.

Press Enter to Proceed.

TestDisk displays the partition table types.

Select the partition table type - usually the default value is the correct one as TestDisk auto-detects the partition table type.

Press Enter to Proceed.

TestDisk displays the menus.

Use the default menu "Analyse" to check your current partition structure and search for lost partitions.

Confirm at Analyse with Enter to proceed.

Read here for more information: http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step